# How to deploy the api manager on a server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to deploy the api manager on a server of the company, but I never did't and I need some help, I already installed the wso2 esb and it's ok, but the new release (3.0) is giving me a localhost link to acess the store and the publisher, so I can't access this from another computer what I'm doing wrong?

Any help will be much apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract a new APIM 3.0 zip and configure `hostname` in `deployment.toml` to be a hostname or a public IP of the server. Then you can use that public IP to access the server.

```
[server]
hostname = "192.168.0.1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I change it, but when I iniciate the wso2server it rewrite the file again, is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: My bad. Fixed the configuration.

Comment: I tried but always rewrite the file to use localhost, I tried this link but didn't do anything
https://www.yenlo.com/blog/running-api-manager-2.5.0-on-a-different-hostname

Comment: You may have not configured the hostname properly. I updated the answer with the correct way. By the way, the above blog is for 2.5 and the configuration model is different in 3.0.

Comment: I did it, and the browser cant find the url, I put this configuration

[server]
hostname = "192.168.0.1"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

Do I need to delete something else?

Comment: Are you sure you gave the correct public IP? can you `ping` that IP from your machine?

Comment: thanks! One more question, there is a way to do the same as the link I put above?

Comment: Since the config model is different, you can use the same configs.